# Windows 10 + WSL Ubuntu + Docker Composer: php-fpm 8.2 is not used

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

So, I have WSL with Ubuntu and Docker Composer Desktop installed. Everything goes smoothly, there are no errors, the images work, the site opens and works correctly, but phpinfo shows that php version 8.0 is used, and not the one that is specified.

Below is my docker-compose file.yml, which builds wordpress, mysql, nginx and php-fpm.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: finatix.mysql
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: finatix_db
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - finatix-network

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: finatix.phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - finatix-network

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
      - nginx
      - php-fpm
    image: wordpress:latest
    container_name: finatix.wordpress
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
      - ./php-config/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: finatix_db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    networks:
      - finatix-network

  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: finatix.nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./app:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - php-fpm
    networks:
      - finatix-network

  php-fpm:
    image: php:8.2-fpm
    container_name: finatix.php-fpm
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: finatix_db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - finatix-network

networks:
  finatix-network:
```

This is an additional config for nginx, which is connected from `/nginx-config/`

```
server {
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

And so it all works, runs and is managed, but the php version is used 8.0, not 8.2, which I connect.

Here I am not interested in the php version itself, 8.0 is also suitable, but the question is why the one I connect is not used)